# Add new value to multiple row

Tags: sql

I have an exsisting database with 700 row where are stored users, let's call this `users`. I will have a new column which is "time_code". Each user have a `time_code`.

I will have these code from an other table where each user_name is associate to a `time_code`, I call this table `time code users`. Is there a way to add these code from `time code users` to `users` at the corresponding name ?

And can I do this only with SQL ?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. If you want assistance, show us sample table data and expected result. Also tag dbms product used, and show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh I don't need to do this now so I can't show you anything, do you have any example of the query needed ?

Comment: The answer could be product specific, and I don't want to waste any time writing an answer for wrong product...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you initial dataset

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (USER_NO NUMBER (3), NAME VARCHAR(5));
CREATE TABLE TIME_CODE_USERS (NAME VARCHAR(5), TIME_CODE VARCHAR(3));


INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (1,'A');
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (2,'B');
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (3,'C');

INSERT INTO TIME_CODE_USERS VALUES ('A', 'GMT');
INSERT INTO TIME_CODE_USERS VALUES ('B', 'IST');
INSERT INTO TIME_CODE_USERS VALUES ('C', 'CET');
```

Now alter the target table to add your column

```
ALTER TABLE USERS ADD  TIME_CODE VARCHAR(3);
```

Run the update to populate the target

```
UPDATE USERS 
SET TIME_CODE = (SELECT TIME_CODE 
                 FROM TIME_CODE_USERS 
                 WHERE USERS.NAME = TIME_CODE_USERS.NAME)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TIME_CODE 
                 FROM TIME_CODE_USERS 
                 WHERE USERS.NAME = TIME_CODE_USERS.NAME);
```

Check the update

```
SELECT * FROM USERS;


| USER_NO | NAME | TIME_CODE |
|---------|------|-----------|
|       1 |    A |       GMT |
|       2 |    B |       IST |
|       3 |    C |       CET |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE u
SET u.time_code = tcu.time_code
FROM users u INNER JOIN time_code_users tcu
    ON u.user_name = tcu.user_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD time_code varchar(40);
UPDATE users SET users.time_code = (
    SELECT time_code FROM time_code_users
    WHERE users.username = time_code_users.username
);
```